# How to load and apply a CSS stylesheet at runtime in a Flex application?

Tags: css, apache-flex, flex3

I'd like to load CSS stylesheets from a URL and apply them to my Flex 3 application at runtime.  Is it possible?

Comment: Are you referring to styling the text in a flex application or styling the application itself (changing the styles of `Panel` etc)?

Comment: Both, styling text and also styling the panels and controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *You cannot load an uncompiled CSS file
>   into your Flex application at run
>   time. You must compile it into a SWF
>   file before loading it.* - Adobe Flex 3 Docs

You can load style sheets (compiled) using the Style Manager.

For the full run-down : [Loading style sheets at run time](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=styles_10.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can load css files at runtime to style the text in a `TextField`.

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("style.css");
loader.load(req);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

private function completeHandler(e:Event):void 
{
  var css:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
  css.parseCSS(e.target.data);
  yourTextField.styleSheet = css;
}
```

As for styling controls, I'm afraid you can't load a text file at run time. May be you can parse it using the `StyleSheet` class - check out the [`styleNames` array](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/StyleSheet.html#styleNames) and the `getStyle` method.

Comment: Thanks alot.  We're going to put styling on the backburner for now until we have time to do the compilation ourselves and/or investigate your suggestion of parsing with StyleSheet class.